# How to make the bookcover a part of my document

Tags: books, book-design, bookcover

I have my document which need a book cover. I independently created the book cover using the `bookcover` document class. I wish to know if there is a way to make this book cover a part of my document. Below is the MWE for my document:

```
% !TeX TS-program = xelatex

\documentclass[12pt,openany,twoside]{book}
\raggedbottom
\let\cleardoublepage=\clearpage
\usepackage[
a4paper,
left=1in,
right=1in, 
top=1in, 
bottom=1in,
]{geometry}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand\HRule{\noindent\rule{\linewidth}{1.5pt}}
\usepackage{background}
\backgroundsetup{contents={}}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{hhline}
\pagestyle{fancy}   
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\begin{document} 
    \chapter{ABC}
    Thdhss dhdhhs swhwhw ejeeeueu rjtttjt yyyiyiyir rrjrjrjrje eegeeegege qgqgqgqgqq hahahahhaah fkffkrkrkrv tottotottotot gotottotot totottototo.
\end{document}
```

Also, the following code from page 30-31 of the `bookcover` package documentation is the MWE for the book cover of my document:

```
\documentclass[
coverwidth=150mm,
coverheight=220mm,
spinewidth=25mm,
bleedwidth=20mm,
markcolor=black,
foldingmargin,
12pt,
% trimmed % Show only trimmed part!
]{bookcover}
%\bookcovertrimmedpart{front} % Trimmed part is the front cover
%\bookcovertrimmedpart{back} % Trimmed part is the back cover
%\bookcovertrimmedpart{spine} % Trimmed part is the spine
\letnamebookcoverpart{front with margin}{front}[5mm,5mm,5mm,5mm]
\letnamebookcoverpart{front upper third}{front with margin}[,2\partheight/3,,]
\letnamebookcoverpart{front lower third}{front with margin}[,,,2\partheight/3]
\letnamebookcoverpart{back with margin}{back}[5mm,5mm,5mm,5mm]
\letnamebookcoverpart{back text area}{back}[27mm,,22mm,27mm]
\letnamebookcoverpart{bg spine bottom}{bg spine}[,,,\partheight-\bleedwidth-\spinewidth]
\newbookcovercomponenttype{center rotate}{
\vfill\centering\rotatebox[origin=c]{-90}{#1}\vfill}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{kantlipsum,microtype}
\usepackage{transparent} % It works only with pdflatex
\begin{document}

\begin{bookcover}
\bookcovercomponent{color}{bg whole}{orange}
\bookcovercomponent{color}{front upper third}{red!60!black}
\bookcovercomponent{color}{front lower third}{red!60!black}
\bookcovercomponent{color}{back with margin}{red!60!black}
\bookcovercomponent{tikz}{front with margin}{
\draw[opacity=0.4,red,line width=10mm] (\partwidth-15mm,0) -- +(0,\partheight);}
\bookcovercomponent{tikz}{back with margin}{
\draw[opacity=0.4,red,line width=10mm] (15mm,0) -- +(0,\partheight);}
\bookcovercomponent{tikz}{whole}[5mm,,5mm,]{
\draw[opacity=0.4,red,line width=10mm] (0,\partheight-20mm) -- +(\partwidth,0);}
\bookcovercomponent{color}{bg spine bottom}{black}
\bookcovercomponent{center}{front upper third}{
\resizebox*{\partwidth-5mm}{\partheight-5mm}{%
\color{white}\transparent{0.1}\bfseries\LaTeX}}
\bookcovercomponent{center}{front lower third}{
\resizebox*{\partwidth-5mm}{\partheight-5mm}{%
\color{white}\transparent{0.1}\bfseries\LaTeX}}
\bookcovercomponent{center}{front}{
\resizebox{90mm}{!}{\bfseries\color{white}\LaTeX}}
\bookcovercomponent{normal}{back text area}{\color{white}\kant[1-2]}
\bookcovercomponent{center rotate}{spine}{
\resizebox{50mm}{!}{\bfseries\color{white}\LaTeX}}
\end{bookcover}
\end{document}
```

Comment: From my (very brief) overview, it looks like a bookcover is a different thing, since it ends up being the back, spine, and front, in that order.  How are you wanting to combine these?  The package pdfpages may be of use.

Comment: I want to incorporate the `bookcover` code in my main document so that I run the combined code to get my document with a book cover. Is not there any way to do this? I know that in Latex, I can create codes in separate `.tex` files and then combine these into 1. Does this apply on the `bookcover` document class as well?

Comment: I see two common ways to go: (1) you're sending this off to become a physical, bound book, in which case the printer will need the bookcover as a separate file (2) you're making this into a pdf or a physical, spiral-bound book, in which case the book cover is really just the first page and you don't need the package.  How is your use case fitting into that distinction?

Comment: I am working on building a single pdf file.

Comment: If the cover is a single "page", you can use \includegrqaphics and crop off hald the image each time (front and back).  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/431250/one-pdf-for-doublepage for example.

Comment: As the code for one class could work or not in another class  (e.g., you cannot use `\chapter{}` in a article class) you mileage may vary combining classes, but in general, is a very bad idea. From hard to easy, you must  decide between:  (1) modify your book class/preamble to admit every command of bookcover  (2) make the cover from the scratch  inside the book class and combien code (3) make the PDF of bookcover and include as image in the book as commented using  pdfpages or croped images,  or  (4) make both PDF documents  separately and join them with some tool like  `pdftk`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the comments.